# Core Foundation equivalent for NSLog

Tags: cocoa, core-foundation

What is the closest Core Foundation function to the functionality of NSLog?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use NSLog?

Comment: The code I'm working with is C, including only the CoreFoundation.h header, and I didn't really want to mess with that just to print a log statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CFShow()` is similar, but without the prefix stuff. Or, as wbyoung says, use `NSLog()`. If you don’t want to use Objective-C, the following is perfectly valid (although it requires linking against Foundation.framework):

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void NSLog(CFStringRef format, ...);
void NSLogv(CFStringRef format, va_list args);
#if __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSLog(CFSTR("Hello, World! %u"), 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: CFShow seems to be what I'm looking for, and thanks for the other suggestion too.

Answer (score 3):

NSLog is built on top of the Apple System Log facility.  Run `man 3 asl` to see the man page for this.  You can use asl directly, but unless there's a reason, you can just keep using NSLog.  Just include and link to Foundation if you want to avoid linking to Cocoa.

You can also just print to stderr if you want.